# Rails link_to with turbolinks and the new hash style

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to, turbolinks

this works nicely

```
= link_to 'All', test_path(:param1 => xxx), 'data-no-turbolink' => true
```

and translates to

```
 <a data-no-turbolink="true" href="/test?param1=xxx">All</a>
```

I want to change it to the new hash syntax so I did this:

```
= link_to 'All', test_path(param1: xxx), data: { no: { turbolink: true }}
```

but it translates to

```
<a data-no="{&quot;turbolink&quot;:true}" href="/test?param1=xxx">All</a>
```

EDIT: This Works:

```
%a{href: "#{test_path(param1: xxx}", data: { no: { turbolink: true }}} All
```

which translates to

```
<a data-no-turbolink href='/test?param1=xxx'>All</a>
```

but shouldn't I stick to `link_to` rather than `<a href></a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some naming conventions, so you must write like this:

```
link_to 'All', test_path(param1: xxx), data: {no_turbolink: true}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always try to use the rails helper methods when they're available. This way you'll get all the benefits of rails: cache-busting and relative pathing and whatever else comes in the future. Given that, the issue in your code is that the `data` hash can only be one level deep. So do this instead:

```
= link_to 'All', test_path(param1: xxx), data: { 'no-turbolink' => true }
```

Note: You can't really use a symbol for the `no-turbolink` part because symbols don't interpret hyphens. https://gist.github.com/misfo/1072693